# .htaccess удаление слеша и index.html

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Помогите найти ошибки в директивах `mod_rewrite`.
Сначала привожу код:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#попытка убрать слеш в конце некоторых УРЛ
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]

#попытка убрать /index.html у страниц каталогов
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html$ -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/index\.html)$ $1 [L,R=301]

#удаление расширения файла у страниц
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

Последняя директива работает.
Первая приводит к циклической переадресации.
Вторая к ошибке

> RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Из-за чего такое может быть? Есть ли альтернативные решения этих задач?

Вообще структура ссылок следующая:
Страницы каталогов в настоящий момент доступны по URL вида *mysite.ru/catalog_page/* и *mysite.ru/catalog_page/index.html*

Первые две директивы призваны сделать чтобы УРЛ каталогов был единообразным и вида *mysite.ru/catalog_page*

Comment: А ответьте мне сначала на тупой вопрос: зачем Вам убирать слеш с каталогов? Чем он Вам помешал?

Comment: СЕО-шники, так их =(